# Tablet stuck in boot animation

Tags: recovery-mode, boot

I have this tablet, [`MSI Primo 91`](http://www.msi.com/product/windpad/Primo_91.html) and just recently I booted into recovery mode in order to wipe the cache. On restart the tablet gets stuck in the manufacturer boot animation and refuses to boot up.

I then tried to reboot into recovery mode when the android laying on its back pops up. The recovery options won't show up.

This guy here.
[image]

The device restarted and gets stuck yet again in boot animation.

I visited the website to download the firmware. I followed the ritual described in the pdf instruction file and I couldn't  recover the tablet.

Right now, I just as stuck as the tablet. How can I fix this?